# Validate form group that contains inputs with checkboxes, should display error message if no checkboxes are selected

Tags: angular, validation, checkbox, angular7

I need to display a validation error message if no checkboxes in my form group are checked. No jquery can be used, all has to be done with angular 7. This is in a reactive form.
I've tried setting ngIf conditions, and apply conditional validation functions, none have been working.
This is one section in my form group containing the checkboxes

```
   initForm() {
      this.financialSectionSix = this.formBuilder.group({
        medicaidOrSssi: [false],
        snap: [false],
        freeOrReducedPriceLunch: [false],
        tanf: [false],
        wic: [false],
        noneOfTheAbove: [false]
       });
     }
```

This is a section of the HTML

```html
<div [hidden]="selectedSectionGroup.sectionSix" class="tab-pane fade show active"
   id="{{financialSectionEnum.SECTION_SIX}}" role="tabpanel">
   <form [formGroup]="financialSectionSix">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="financial1">
      <input required formControlName="medicaidOrSssi" id="medicaidOrSssi" class="form-check-input"
         data-hint="yes" type="checkbox" value="true">
      Medicaid or Supplemental Security Income (SSI)
      </label>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="cada-form-student-financial-section-6-1-2">
      <input required formControlName="snap" id="snap" class="form-check-input" data-hint="yes" type="checkbox"
         value='true'>
      Food Stamps or Supplemental Nutrition Assistance Program (SNAP)
      </label>
   </form>
</div>
```

When checking one of the boxes, the value should change from false to true, and if unselected, should change from true to false.

Comment: Tried using `Validators.required`? `medicaidOrSssi: [false, Validators.required]`

Comment: I have not, where would I put that snippet of code to test?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a custom validator for this one, something like:

```
  selectAtleastOne(c: FormGroup) {
    const selectAtleastOne = Object.values(c.value).some(Boolean);
    return selectAtleastOne ? null : {
      selectAtleastOne: {
        valid: false,
        error: true
      }
    };
  }
```

You can use it like:

```
this.financialSectionSix = this.formBuilder.group({
          medicaidOrSssi: [false],
          snap: [false],
          freeOrReducedPriceLunch: [false],
          tanf: [false],
          wic: [false],
          noneOfTheAbove: [false]
        }, { validator: this.selectAtleastOne });
```

And in HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="financialSectionSix">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="financial1">
      <input required formControlName="medicaidOrSssi" id="medicaidOrSssi" class="form-check-input"
         data-hint="yes" type="checkbox" value="true">
      Medicaid or Supplemental Security Income (SSI)
      </label><br>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="cada-form-student-financial-section-6-1-2">
      <input required formControlName="snap" id="snap" class="form-check-input" data-hint="yes" type="checkbox"
         value='true'>
      Food Stamps or Supplemental Nutrition Assistance Program (SNAP)
      </label>
      <div style="color: red" *ngIf="financialSectionSix?.errors?.selectAtleastOne?.error">Select atleaset one</div>
      <br>
      <div>{{financialSectionSix.value | json}}</div>
   </form>
```

Check a live demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxwkby